# Does resetting box-sizing do any harm in on iOS safari web?

Tags: ios, css, web, safari

Since I'm using this block of reset css:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I see constantly `:before` and `:after` blinking in the Safari web inspector, when scrolling or other rerendering events.

If so how can I still reset box-sizing for all elements in iOS Safari.

Comment: er gaat mij weer niemand helpen e

Answer (score 0):

It is the finest way for all browser as of now.
But you can also use like this if needed:

```
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```